Stop gamepad from controlling windows
I have a generic Bluetooth gamepad that I'm using to control minecraft Java. I'm using the midnight controls mod with unfocused input turned on so I can click out of the game window and then do other tasks on a separate monitor with my mouse and keyboard while the gamepad continues to control the game. The reason is so a second person can play while I'm working. Everything mostly works but when I open any windows menu like settings etc the gamepad acts like a mouse and controls both minecraft and the windows menu at the same time. How can I make the gamepad only control minecraft and nothing else?
Want to note that I'm not using steam.
I've tried disabling various drivers in the controller settings but they all make the gamepad disconnect completely.

Know that at best, this gamepad is a hack.  As such, it will probably never operate as a first class device without bugs like this.  Windows only supports one cursor/input at a time per-user session.  Anything else is an unsanctioned hack.  Sorry I don't have a solution.  If you look through the release notes of any such product, you will see fix after pointless fix from not playing by the rules.  I do wish you good luck with this.
